# What is causing this KeyStore Exception?

Tags: android, android-studio, dji-sdk

I'm trying to run DJI's importSDKDemo [sample code](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-ImportAndActivateSDKInAndroidStudio/tree/master/ImportSDKDemo) on an Android smartwatch, and I get a KeyStore exception in startSDKRegistration() when the instance of DJISDKManager tries to register the application.

> DJI SDK: v4.9
>
> Android SDK (compileSDKversion) : 28
>
> Android Device: Mobvoi TicWatch Pro 0584 with Wear OS v2.6

The Mobvoi TicWatch is connected to a specific WiFi Network in my workplace, with the modem just nearby, as to make sure it wasn't related to the public WiFi Network I previously used

I couldn't find any information concerning this specific problem except this issue report, I tried applying the solution proposed there but I still get the [KeyStore exceptions](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/389)

I'm not sure which code to include in this post but here's the part where the program stops, after the DJISDKManager.getInstance.registerApp(...) which is normally the exact same version as in the importSDKDemo.

```
private void startSDKRegistration() {
        if (isRegistrationInProgress.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("registering, pls wait...");
                    DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), new DJISDKManager.SDKManagerCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRegister(DJIError djiError) {
                            if (djiError == DJISDKError.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
                                showToast("Register Success");
                                DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();
                            } else {
                                showToast("Register sdk fails, please check the bundle id and network connection!");
                            }
                            Log.v(TAG, djiError.getDescription());
                        }
```

And here's the full stack of the KeyStore exception I get several times :

```
W/KeyStore: KeyStore exception
    android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 7)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1964)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
        at android.security.IKeystoreService$Stub$Proxy.get(IKeystoreService.java:786)
        at android.security.KeyStore.get(KeyStore.java:195)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetCertificate(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:144)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getCertificate(KeyStore.java:1120)
        at android.security.net.config.KeyStoreCertificateSource.ensureInitialized(KeyStoreCertificateSource.java:61)
        at android.security.net.config.KeyStoreCertificateSource.findBySubjectAndPublicKey(KeyStoreCertificateSource.java:77)
        at android.security.net.config.CertificatesEntryRef.findBySubjectAndPublicKey(CertificatesEntryRef.java:47)
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityConfig.findTrustAnchorBySubjectAndPublicKey(NetworkSecurityConfig.java:123)
        at android.security.net.config.TrustedCertificateStoreAdapter.getTrustAnchor(TrustedCertificateStoreAdapter.java:51)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.findTrustAnchorBySubjectAndPublicKey(TrustManagerImpl.java:945)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:487)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:208)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:404)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(Unknown Source:65)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(Unknown Source:54)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(Unknown Source:202)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(Unknown Source:247)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(Unknown Source:0)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(Unknown Source:22)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:26)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:165)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:6)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:137)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:165)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:6)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:160)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:165)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:60)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:165)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:6)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Unknown Source:114)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(Unknown Source:4)
        at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(Unknown Source:17)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I expect the registration to unfold normally, I'm getting the "Hello Round World" screen and the "Registering pls wait..." showToast message, but after several KeyStore Exceptions I'm getting the "Register sdk fails, please check the bundle id and network connection!" message from OnRegister(DJIError djiError)
with the DJIError being

```
djiError = {DJISDKError@14580} "The metadata received from server is invalid, please reconnect to the server and try."
```

If the registration is completed normally, the user should get the "Register Success" showToast message.

Does anyone know what could cause those KeyStore Exceptions ?

Thank you for your time !